# Memory leak (?) on WPF Panel containing WPF scrollviewer and hosting WindowsFormsHost inside that

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF Panel contains a WPF ScrollViewer - which in turn is hosting various WinForms usercontrols  within a WindowsFormsHost. Now, sometimes, when I resize the inner content of the Scrollviewer (i.e The WindowsFormsHost) to get the scrollbars into action, I see a terrible lag in performance of the resizing of the whole panel. Dubegging into it, I noticed Panel_SizeChanged event handler is getting hit continuously during these lags (whereas it's getting hit only 1 or 2 times when I'm experiencing no lags). Could someone point me to where the problem might be ?

Should I try putting the main WPF panel itself inside the WPF scrollviewer ?

```
public MyWPFPanel()
{
    this.Content = new ScrollViewer() { Content = new WindowsFormsHost() { Child = _grid, ClipToBounds = true, }, CanContentScroll = true, HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto ,VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto };
    AllowClose = false;
}
```

Comment: What is the code in the size changed handler? Anything?

Comment: Forgot to add something. _grid from the code above is a WinForms Panel (That is where the WinForms User Controls are getting placed). And the SizeChanged of that panel is handled like this :

foreach(var control in this.Controls)
            {
                if(control is ControlContainer)
                {
                    (control as ControlContainer).AdjustPosAndSize(this.Width, this.Height);
                }
            }

There are no recursive calls.

Comment: That might be a recursive call in the OnResize, the sizes of controls are resized which might affect the parent to resize which raises the SizeChanged again.